# Read the contents of a file again and again in Fortran 95

Tags: file, fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I want to read entries from a huge file (more than 10^10 rows) inside a loop. Since file is huge, I am reading one element at a time, using it and then reading the next element and so on. Thus, I have something like this:

```
DO i = 1, 10
    open(unit = 1, file = 'myfile.dat')
    Do j = 1, 10^10
         read(1, *)x
         !Use x here
    Enddo
    close(1)
ENDDO
```

This works fine when the outer loop runs a small number of times. However, when I want try to run it many more times, (say 100 to 1000), my computer gets hung or throws an error : `Not enough space on \tmp`. I looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199565/not-enough-space-on-tmp) but that didn't solve my issue. My primary guess is that this is happening because each time I re-open the file, it gets stored in RAM or tmp but I am not sure about this. In this context, can anybody tell me a better way to load file only once but read the contents over and over ?

Comment: could you give us a correct compilable example. For instance 10^10 is not Fortran. I also would like to see the definition of x...

Comment: @FrancoisJacq : Yes `10^10` is not a fortran and is not meant to be anywhere in my question.  I have properly code-blocked my Fortran snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to close the file, just "rewind" it:

```
open(newunit = iunit, file = 'myfile.dat') !no need to specify the number, the compiler will do it for you, iunit is an integer
do i = 1, 10
    do j = 1, 10**10                       !fortran compilable
         read(iunit, *)x
         !Use x here
    end do
    rewind(iunit)        
end do

close(iunit)
```

Comment: Yes I found this. Thanks anyway!